# State machine pattern with overlapping responsibilities

Tags: c#, state-machine

So, I'm working on a project in Unity (with C# scripts, though the question is largely language-agnostic), and I'm representing the various game states with a very simple state machine.

```
public enum State
{
    Initialized,
    ShowBriefing,
    Running,
    Quitting
};
```

In my GameStateController class, I handle some commands from the network, let's say it looks like this:

```
if (gameState.CurrentState == GameState.State.Initialized) {
    HandleGameCommand ();
    NetworkInterface.Instance.HandlePresenceMessages ();                
} else if (gameState.CurrentState == GameState.State.ShowBriefing) {
    HandleGameCommand ();
    NetworkInterface.Instance.HandlePresenceMessages ();                
} else if (gameState.CurrentState == GameState.State.Running) { 
    HandleGameCommand ();

    if (lookTargets.Count > 0) {
        // do some stuff
    }

    NetworkInterface.Instance.HandlePresenceMessages ();
} else if (gameState.CurrentState == GameState.State.Quitting) {
    NetworkInterface.Instance.Close ();
    Application.Quit ();                
}
```

And HandleGameCommand generally looks like this:

```
Messages.GameCommand gameCommand = NetworkInterface.Instance.NextMessage<Messages.GameCommand> ("game.command");

if (gameCommand != null) {

    switch (gameCommand.type) {
    case "show-briefing":
        // Show the mission briefing. Currently a NOOP.
        if (gameState.CurrentState == GameState.State.Initialized) {
            gameState.CurrentState = GameState.State.ShowBriefing;
        }

        // Do some other stuff
        break;
    case "run":
        // Set the gameState to Running and respond
        gameState.CurrentState = GameState.State.Running;       
        // Do some other stuff
        break;
    case "detect-look-at":
        if (gameState.CurrentState == GameState.State.Running) {
            lookTargets.Add (json ["target"] as string);
        }
    // And so on
```

My question is - what is a better way to do this? I like having a unified GameCommand handler, but I don't like that I have to have if-elses within the GameCommand handler to detect what State I'm in.

I could make separate "HandleGameCommand()" methods for each State - HandleGameCommand-Initialized(), HandleGameCommand-ShowBriefing(), but that seems sloppy.

I could create a `Dictionary<State, List<string>>`, and prebuild a list of which commands to handle for each state.

Is there a solid pattern for doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why does separate "HandleGameCommand()" methods seem sloppy?  Seems sloppier to me to have one method try to do everything.

Comment: Because each method would be remarkably similar to each other in structure. Maybe I'm trying to over-engineer this, but it should be possible to have a method that implements the framework of getting a GameCommand and switching on the type, and simply pass in a map of strings and delegates.